# How to replicate C# string encryption in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, encryption

I need to send an encrypted password to the api,
but I can't find how to replicate this encryption in flutter.

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
        {
            byte[] salt;
            byte[] bytes;
            if (password == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
            }
            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveByte = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 16, 1000))
            {
                salt = rfc2898DeriveByte.Salt;
                bytes = rfc2898DeriveByte.GetBytes(32);
            }
            byte[] numArray = new byte[49];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, numArray, 1, 16);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, numArray, 17, 32);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(numArray);
        }
```

I tried with AES with the package pointycastle  and encrypt

Comment: Repeat after me: hashing is not encryption. Did you look up the Flutter implementation of Rfc2898? First result on Google: https://pub.dev/packages/pbkdf2ns/score

Comment: What did you try? Show you attempt using https://pub.dev/documentation/pointycastle_base/latest/pointycastle.impl.key_derivator.pbkdf2/PBKDF2KeyDerivator-class.html After that you are just going to copy two bits to a 49 byes list and base64 it.